# Pandas Multilevel header, creating multiple rows for entries within a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-level

I have a multilevel column pandas dataframe with orders from an online retailer. Each line has info from a single order. This results in multiple items within the same row. I need to create a single row for each item sold in the orders. Because of this there are hundreds of columns.

```
     orderID    orderinfo       orderline    orderline    orderline    orderline
     nan        orderaspect1    0            0            1            1
     nan        nan             itemaspect1  itemaspect2  itemaspect1  itemaspect2
0    1          2               3            4            5            6
1   10          20              30           40           50           60
2  100          200             300          400          500          600
```

each row with the same number under orderline needs to have its own row which includes the info from order iD and all the order aspects. It needs to look something like this.

```
     orderID    orderinfo       orderline    orderline    item #
     nan        nan             itemaspect1  itemaspect2  
0    1          2               3            4            0
1   10          20              30           40           0
2  100          200             300          400          0
3    1          2               5            6            1
4   10          20              50           60           1
5  100          200             500          600          1
```

This way there is a row for each ITEM instead of a row for each ORDER.
I've tried using melt and stack to unpivot followed by pivoting but I've run into issue with that and the multiindex columns. Nothing is formatting it correctly.

[edit]
It should look like this using code.

```
 i = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2011-03-31', '2011-04-01', '2011-04-04', '2011-04-05',

                   '2011-04-06', '2011-04-07', '2011-04-08', '2011-04-11',
                   '2011-04-12', '2011-04-13'])
    cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['orderID', "orderlines"],['order data', 0, 1]])
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(len(i), 6)),index=i, columns=cols)
```

Comment: Could you provide us a minimum reproducible example ?

Comment: I edited the original post to include the code. Thanks!